# Dealing with difference between JavaScript and PHP's months when using a JQuery countdown timer

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, countdown

I retrieve a date from the database (via query). It comes in this format: `2013-04-08`. In PHP I get `promotion_end_dates` for each product inside a loop and add a JQuery countdown script. The problem is that when I call the countdown function:

```
$(".clock").countdown({until: new Date(<?php echo $promo_date;?>)});
```

the counter counts with 1 month/30 days more because of the different ways of month counting between PHP and JavaScript.

How do make I `$promo_date` correspond to the correct JavaScript month?

Comment: convert it to the right format that [JavaScript expects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: The date format of `countdown` is configurable. You have to be sure to use the same format in PHP and JS.

Comment: I am sure that could be configured, but how :)

Answer (score 1):

given that your mysql table holds dates in `YYYY-mm-dd` format

add following after your mysql query

```
$promo_date_exp = explode('-', $promo_date);
```

and replace your particular Javascript line with this line

```
$(".clock").countdown({until: new Date(<?php echo $promo_date_exp[0].','. ($promo_date_exp[1]- 1).','.$promo_date_exp[2]?>)});
```

Comment: Ejay + 1 for your answer, Thanks mate !

Answer (score 0):

You have to  send php date to javascript as a string

```
$(".clock").countdown({until: new Date("<?php echo $promo_date;?>")});
```

Comment: you mean string like the one I can get with unix_timestamp(promotion_end_date) from the query? sorry if I didn't understand you

Answer (score 0):

You should format your date properly. From the documentation on [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), you should format it according to rfc 2822.

```
$(".clock").countdown({
    until: new Date('<?php echo date('r', strtotime($promo_date)); ?>')
});
```